# Why does protobuf include datatype in the serialized data?

Tags: protocol-buffers

Protobuf includes datatype in the serialized data (Thrift does it too). However, the application reading the data should be able to get this information from the schema.

The only scenario I can think of that can benefit from this design is the users completely lose the schema information. Say, their machine is completely broken and the source code and the schema is not stored at anywhere else. And they are trying to restore the data from the hard drive which needs the deserialized data to be self contained. But I doubt this design is to cover this extremely rare case.

Plus, excluding the data type in the serialization can definitely save space to some degree without hurting the runtime performance. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Protobuf includes datatype in the serialized data

Not usually, it doesn't. The only time it does this is if you are using the `Any` type (when it needs it to know which `message` you stored), or if you're using a library with some non-standard support for type metadata. It absolutely does not store anything about the type normally - just the field numbers and wire types. I suspect you have misunderstood something about the data that you are looking at.

---

If you *mean* the wire type; it needs that to be able to **skip** (or store verbatim, for round-trip) the fields that it **doesn't** know about (things that were *not* in the schema it was generated from). The wire type is *not* enough information to understand the field contents - it is very ambiguous without the schema - for example "length prefixed" can represent at least 4 different data types. Ultimately, it is 3 bits and is packed *along with* the field number; most of the time (well, four-sevenths, including fields 1-15) it doesn't even cost an extra byte.

To put this into perspective, in xml, the rules for finding the end of the current value would be:

- if it is an attribute, look for a closing `"`
- if it is an element, look for a closing `</theElementName>` (taking into account any nesting)

The wire type here defines the same thing:

- for varint: read up to (and including) the next byte (at most 10 expected) that doesn't have the high bit set
- for 64-bit: read 8 bytes
- for 32-bit: read 4 bytes
- for length delimted: read a varint, then read that many bytes
- for start group: read to the matching end group (taking into account any nesting)

So it is all about telling you when to *stop*, if you can't know that already because you didn't expect that field.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation Marc. I am reading the book 'Designing Data-Intensive Applications' where it talks about the protobuf encoding in the section 'Thrift and Protocols' which gives an example in Figure 4-4 (sorry my rank on stackoverflow does not allow me to insert a screenshot). Although it does not mention this 'wire type' details, looks to me the type it is talking about is this and that would make a lot sense to me - all the type are in 3 bits which share the same byte with field tag (I definitely do not believe Google would design something that is not that efficient :)).

Comment: That said, I am still confused about the example in which all 3 different strings 'Martin', 'daydreaming' and 'hacking' have the same encoded wire type '010'. Moreover, it has some text above the encoded type and implies they stand for strings. Does this make sense to you?

Comment: @CodingFanSteve the 010 here is wire type 2, "length prefixed", which just means that the length is stated as a varint after the field header. All UTF-8 `string` data uses wire type 2. But 3 other data types do too.